# How can I show a ToolTip for a short period of time after clicking on a Button using attached-behaviors?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tooltip, attachedbehaviors

I want to display a `ToolTip` of a `Button` immediately after clicking on it. The `ToolTip` should then disappear after a short period of time. This is needed only as a feedback for the user since clicking on the `Button` causes a string to be copied to the Clipboard.

I used an Button-Behavior to display the `Tooltip` of the Button via the Click-Event. To display the `ToolTip` I set its `IsOpen` property to true.

```
class ForceToolTipBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.Click += AssociatedObject_Click;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tooltip = this.AssociatedObject.ToolTip as ToolTip;

        tooltip = new ToolTip();

        tooltip.Content = "Log was copied to your Clipboard";

        tooltip.IsOpen = true;        
    }
}
```

This works just fine but the `ToolTip` stays open. Is there any elegant way make the `ToolTip` disappear after like a second? Is it possible to use the `ToolTipService` for that task?

Comment: tooltip.AutoPopDelay = x; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and quick way:

```
private void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tooltip = this.AssociatedObject.ToolTip as ToolTip;

    tooltip = new ToolTip();

    tooltip.Content = "Log was copied to your Clipboard";

    tooltip.IsOpen = true;  

    HideToolTip(tooltip);   
}

private async void HideToolTip(ToolTip toolTip)
{
    await Task.Delay(3 * 1000); // 3 second
    toolTip.IsOpen = false;
}
```